# How to have new fields show with default content on new items?

Tags: entities

For example:

I created a content type with 2 fields, the default values are:

```
Field 1 = A
Field 2 = B
```

When creating BRAND new content items, the fields show up on display with populated default data:

```
A
B
```

But when editing content that was created BEFORE creating the fields it doesn't work.

Is it normal that the default fields will only work on NEW content items?

I want to be able to add fields to items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it normal that the default fields will only work on NEW content items?

Yes, that is normal.

The way I work around that to update the OLD fields:

1. Go to the database and export the field table.

   - For format: select **CSV** (do not select "CSV for MS Excel")
2. Open the .csv file in Excel and make changes to the values.

   - To replicate a cel fast in excel, highlight 1 cel and move mouse to the right bottom corner of the cel (cursor will change to a **+**), then hold down left click and scroll down.
3. Import back to the DB and check-mark "replace table data with file".
4. In Drupal, clear/flush the caches to see changes.

Comment: Wow! That sounds like a lot of work...isn't there a module to automate this, maybe VBO or something? How can I avoid having to go into PHPmyadmin  to do this?

Comment: For me it feels quick, but yeah, if you want to avoid using phpmyadmin, then VBO should do the trick.

Comment: I'm in PHPmyadmin now, but can't find the field in question, it's a display suite field called  field_quote  , how to find it, search it?

Comment: Use the "filter items by name" box, under your database name. (top left) Then just type quote.

Comment: table name should be field_data_field_quote